# Frame of reference and change in potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, potential-energy

If we consider a block moving with velocity $v$ towards a horizontal spring whose one end is fixed on a wall (spring is mass less) and an observer B attached to the block.When the block compresses the spring completely and stops then what according to observer B causes increase in potential energy of spring?

Comment: If the wall is massless, the spring will not be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is of course ** the observer himself and the block **. The observer will experience deceleration in his non-inertial frame which making it losses its own kinetic energy and which has transfered to store in the spring as potential energy.

Comment: can u please precisely name the force responsible and also whether the work done by this force is positive or negative which is increasing P.E. of spring

Comment: one more thing according to observer B there is no change in its own kinetic energy

Comment: Energy is always conserved. Thats why observer's B own kinetic energy has to be decreased in order to change to the potential energy inside spring.

Comment: but there is also external force acting due to wall on spring so mechanical energy need not be conserved